Positivity for a kinetic PDE
Let us consider the following kinetic equation:
$$ \partial_t f + v \cdot \partial_x f = \rho[f] \, M[T] - f $$
for a the phase space density $f=f(x,v,t)$ on $\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty)$ with respect to the positive initial condition
\begin{aligned}
 0 < f(x, v, 0) &= f_0(x, v) \in L^1(\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}).
 \end{aligned}
$\mathbb{T}^1$ is here the one-dimensional flat torus and $\rho[f](x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,v,t) \, dv$ the macroscopic density. \begin{equation}
 M[T](v) := \left( {\pi T} \right)^{-1/2} \exp \left( - \frac{|v|^2}{T} \right) > 0
 \end{equation} with a given function $T(x,t) \geq c > 0$ is the well-known normalized Maxwell distribution.
A mild formulation is implicitly given by
\begin{equation} \label{reg nonlin kinetic}
 f(x,v,t) = \mathrm{e}^{-t}f_0(x-vt,v) + \int_{0}^{t} \mathrm{e}^{s-t} \rho(x-v(t-s),s) M[T(x-v(t-s),s)](v) \, \mathrm{d}s.
 \end{equation}
I would like to show the positivity of $f.$ But I have no idea how to perform here. My first thought was a Gronwall-like-argument. Would be very grateful for any help and hints!
(I posted this question earlier at MO too: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/478281/positivity-for-a-kinetic-pde)
EDIT: Derivation of the mild form by method of characteristics
Let $g(x,v,t) := \rho(x,t)M[T(x,t)](v).$ Then we are considering the equation:
$$ \partial_t f + v \cdot \partial_x f + f= g.  $$
Along the characteristics $x(t) = x_0 + vt$ we can reduce this equation to
$$ \partial_t \tilde{f} + \tilde{f}= \tilde{g},  $$
by setting $\tilde{f}(x,v,t) = f(x_0 + vt,v,t). $
We obtain a linear ODE w.r.t to $t$ and inhomogeneity $g.$ The solution of this equation is
$$ \tilde{f} = \mathrm{e}^{-t}\tilde{f}_0(x,v) + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{s-t} \tilde{g} \, (x(s),s,v) \mathrm{d}s.$$
Switching back to $f$:
$$ {f} = \mathrm{e}^{-t}{f}_0(x_0,v) + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{s-t} {g} \, (x_0 + vs,s,v) \mathrm{d}s.$$
And substituting back $x_0 = x(t) -vt$ gives the mild form:
$$ {f}(x,v,t) = \mathrm{e}^{-t}{f}_0(x-vt,v) + \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{s-t} {g} \, (x - v(t-s),s,v) \mathrm{d}s.$$
